# AngularJS: how to avoid the nonassign error when providing default values to missing attributes?

Tags: angularjs, exception, angularjs-directive

This is a question & answer case, because I struggled a bit with the issue, so I wish to keep track of it and its solution.
Hoping it can help somebody, and perhaps other people can provide alternative solutions.

My case: I had to work on a large AngularJS 1.4.6 project (I will name it prj), written in TypeScript, defining a number of directives (prj-ddd) with various attributes (prj-aaa), some of them being boolean.
They implemented these boolean attributes with string binding: `prjEnabled: "@"` or `prjRequired: "@"`.
So they tested the values like so: `if ($scope.prjEnabled === "false")`, or in templates: `<div ng-show="prjRequired === 'true'">` (yeah, no controllerAs usage as well...).
These attributes are optional: obviously, here, `prjEnabled` defaults to `"true"`, and `prjRequired` defaults to `"false"`, among others, because the tests are `false` when these values are `undefined`.

This is verbose, inelegant (IMO), prone to errors (lot of raw strings, implicit default value), and not very efficient (although probably not in a perceptible way).

So I started to replace these bindings with expression / two-way binding: `prjEnabled: "="` and `prjRequired: "="`.
Thus, when AngularJS sees `<prj-component prj-enabled="false">`, it provides directly a boolean in the directive's scope.
Nice touch: with such literal values, it creates no binding, so no performance hit.
I have to cope with absent attribute, so I added in the `link` function of the directives something like:

```
if (scope.prjEnabled === undefined) {
    scope.prjEnabled = true;
}
```

And the usages become: `if (!$scope.prjEnabled)`, or in templates: `<div ng-show="prjRequired">`.

So far, so good. But we also have explicit bindings: `<prj-component prj-enabled="{{someScopeValue}}">` or even `<prj-component prj-enabled="{{foo.canEdit && bar.valid}}">`.
Since we have two-way bindings, I just replaced them with: `<prj-component prj-enabled="someScopeValue">` or `<prj-component prj-enabled="foo.canEdit && bar.valid">`.
Well, if `someScopeValue` is `undefined`, the directive will detect that and provide the default value, which will go up to the parent scope. Annoying, but in most cases, probably harmless. The real value is generally provided later (eg. after a network request).
But sometime, I have the following error in the console:

> https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=foo.canEdit%20%26%26%20bar.valid&p1=prjComponent

I followed the advice given in the corresponding page, replacing the bindings with `"=?"`, but I still have the error.

Ideally, I would replace these bindings with `"<?"`, avoiding the first issue (overwriting the value in the parent's scope) and the second one (no assignment to an expression).
But this needs AngularJS 1.5+, and I cannot upgrade the version in the current project.

So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was tricky and I had to try various solutions, until I saw the light and remembered that with `"=?"` binding, there is a way to distinguish an absent attribute from one with an `undefined` value.
I rewrote the default value assignment as such:
`if (!("prjEnabled" in scope)) { scope.prjEnabled = true; }`
If you are not familiar with the `in` operator, it is roughly equivalent to `scope.hasOwnProperty("prjEnabled")`, but it also checks the prototype hierarchy. I use it mostly because it is nicer / terser than the function call...

I made a Plunkr application (out of an official AngularJS one) to reproduce the error, to see when it happens, and to explore various cases: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z2AIag?p=preview

It shows that with `"="` binding and assigning default value if undefined, the error appears when the attribute is empty (an unlikely case) or when AngularJS silently captures an exception (here `wrong.scopeValue && wrong.unknown` where `$scope.wrong` doesn't exist, causing the ReferenceError exception) and provides `undefined` as value.
With `"=?"`, we still have the second issue (the empty attribute value case doesn't throw).
If we test with the `"x" is scope` method, we get rid of this annoying case, quite common when `wrong` is a variable filled later (network update, etc.).
The only case where the error can still happen is if we assign a value to the bound attribute, and only in the `wrong` case.

Answer (score 0):

### How to manually create one-way binding with default value:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            //oneWay: "<?"
        },
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink (scope, elem, attrs) {
        if (!attrs.oneWay) {
            scope.oneWay = defaultValue;
        } else {
            scope.$watch(attrs.oneWay, function(value) {
                scope.oneWay = value;
            });
        };
    }       
})
```

For versions of AngularJS (<1.5) that do not have one-way binding, it can be implemented with a watcher.